# Returning DataFrame from one class to another class

Tags: python, database, dataframe, csv, pyodbc

I am trying to create 2 python classes, class CsvtoDataFrame for moving data from csv to DataFrame. and class DataFrametoDB from Dataframe to database. When I am trying to return the dataframe from CsvtoDataFrame and print it. It says "<**main**.CsvtoDataFrame object at 0x00981890>" How can I see the data of the dataframe outside the CsvtoDataFrame . I need help in this. Please!

import pandas as pd

class CsvtoDataFrame:
global pd_sales
def **init**(self,FileName):
self.FileName = FileName
pd_sales=pd.read_csv(FileName)
#print(pd_sales)
def ReturnFile(self):
return pd_sales

class DataFrametoDB:
def **init**(self,obj):
self.pd_sales=obj.pd_sales
print(self.pd_sales)
df=CsvtoDataFrame('test.csv')
print(df)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eq1B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return pd_sales, you may need to create another function, insteading of doing in def **init**(self, FileName).

```
import pandas as pd

class CsvtoDataFrame: 
    global pd_sales 

    def __init__(self,File): 
        self.FileName = File
        
        #print(pd_sales) 
    def readcvs(self):
        pd_sales=pd.read_csv(self.FileName)
        return pd_sales;


class DataFrametoDB: 
    def __init__(self,obj): 
        self.pd_sales=obj.pd_sales 
        print(self.pd_sales)


df=CsvtoDataFrame('test.csv')
df2=df.readcvs()
print(df2)
```